# Nativescript - page.frame is undefined

Tags: nativescript

Following the examples at [this page](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/frame) I'm trying to navigate a user from the login page to the home page but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code

```
var page;
exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args){
    page = args.object;
    const frame = page.frame;
    page.bindingContext = loginVM;

    console.log(frame);              //undefined
    if(settings.hasKey('token')){
        frame.navigate({
            moduleName: 'home/home-page',
            clearHistory: true
        });
    }
}
```

With this I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

This code does work however

```
const frameModule = require('ui/frame');
var page;

exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args){
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = loginVM;

    if(settings.hasKey('token')){
        frameModule.topmost().navigate({
            moduleName: 'home/home-page',
            clearHistory: true
        });
    }
}
```

The docs seems to be using the first style of code everywhere. Why is it not working?

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Use `loaded` event on Page to ensure that you can get a frame reference via `page.frame` (only when the page is fully loaded it will have frame property set-up). Otherwise, you can set a unique `id` on your frame and get it via `getFrameById` - see this Playground for demonstration of the above: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=HEEICi&v=2